# Resizing logical volume with no free extents but with free disk space

Tags: linux, lvm, xfs

I have a 7.9 TB logical volume formatted with XFS filesystem. I have 8 1 TB RAID devices as physical volumes, and 1 volume group that contains all of these devices. I have 2.5 TB free space on my logical volume. I'd like to remove 2 of the 1 TB devices from the volume group since I don't "need" them anymore. Reading the man page of pvmove, it seems like I would need to create at least 5.5 TB of space and pvmove everything from the current 1 TB volumes onto the new volumes, and then remove all 8 of the original volumes from the logical volume. This seems onerous. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

There's no problem on the LVM side. Use `lvreduce` to shrink a volume group; obviously, if there's a filesystem on it, you mustn't shrink it below the size of the filesystem. Then use `pvmove` to shuffle extents around: `pvmove /dev/sdz42` removes extents from the physical volume `/dev/sdz42` to other physical volumes in the same volume group, after which you can decommission the physical volume with `vgreduce`.

However this is moot since you have an XFS filesystem, and [XFS does not support shrinking](http://xfs.org/index.php/XFS_FAQ#Q%3a_Is_there_a_way_to_make_a_XFS_filesystem_larger_or_smaller.3F). I'm afraid you'll have to move the data off and remake the filesystem (and thus you can be completely unsubtle with LVM).

Comment: Gilles, excellent, I just did not get the correct workflow! lvreduce does exactly what is required... and now I see that I have really hurt myself with XFS.